# C# FindBySubjectName function

Tags: c#, security, find, certificate, x509certificate

Why does a search for `TEXT 141` also find `TEXT 14`:

```cs
foundCertificates = certificates.Find(
                    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "TEXT 14", false);
foundCertificates = certificates.Find(
                    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "TEXT 141", false);
```

If I specify I want `TEXT 141` it shouldn't select `TEXT 14` for me.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509findtype(v=vs.110).aspx) for `X509FindType.FindBySubjectName` enumeration member:

> Using the `FindBySubjectName` value, the `Find` method performs a case-insensitive string comparison using the supplied value. For example, if you pass "MyCert" to the `Find` method, it will find all certificates with the subject name *containing* that string, regardless of other subject values. Searching by distinguished name is a more precise search.

So, if you want a precise match, use `X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName` instead.

Comment: Tnx. But when I search for "TEXT 141" in FindBySubjectDistinguishedName it says it doesn't find certificate. Where can I see the SubjectDistinguishedName of a certificate?

Comment: @StevenSeagull, open the certificate details -> Details tab -> Subject field. Here is an [example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IXYUJ.png).

Comment: Got it! 

X500DistinguishedName name = certificate.SubjectName;
Console.WriteLine(name.Name);

Tnx it works now

Comment: In case of the "FindBySubjectDistinguishedName", if you're feeding to the Find method your own string literal you need to prepend it with "CN=", in my case it wasn't able to find any cert otherwise. Example: Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, "CN=example.org", ...).